# Remove Parent Element from Multidimensional Array If Certain Elements Of The Array Are Equal

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, duplicates

I have an array of arrays, as shown below.  This array contains 3 arrays, and each of the 3 arrays have 18 elements.  I want to remove the entire parent array (either [0], [1], [2]) if all 18 of the elements within the array are the same as the 18 elements within any of the other arrays, with the exception of the [transaction_id] and the [date].  So the remaining 16 elements would have to be the same in order for the array to be considered duplicate and the parent array removed from the array.

Any help would be appreciated.  I have searched through this website but cannot find a question on this particular issue.

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [transaction_id] => 3474
        [date] => 2011-09-20
        [location] => Kansas City
        [year] => 2005
        [year_diff] => 0
        [make] => Ford
        [make_id] => 19
        [model] => F150 Sc Cab
        [model_id] => 478
        [subseries] => Lariat
        [color] => Dk Grn
        [doors] => X
        [cylinders] => 8
        [radio] => CD
        [odometer] => 78029
        [odometer_difference] => -4971
        [odometer_difference_abs] => 4971
        [price] => 9400
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [transaction_id] => 1843
        [date] => 2011-09-21
        [location] => Kansas City
        [year] => 2005
        [year_diff] => 0
        [make] => Ford
        [make_id] => 19
        [model] => F150 Sc Cab
        [model_id] => 478
        [subseries] => Lariat
        [color] => Dk Grn
        [doors] => X
        [cylinders] => 8
        [radio] => CD
        [odometer] => 78029
        [odometer_difference] => -4971
        [odometer_difference_abs] => 4971
        [price] => 9400
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [transaction_id] => 7778
        [date] => 2011-10-05
        [location] => Kansas City
        [year] => 2005
        [year_diff] => 0
        [make] => Ford
        [make_id] => 19
        [model] => F150 Crew Cab
        [model_id] => 19
        [subseries] => XLT
        [color] => Blue
        [doors] => C
        [cylinders] => 8
        [radio] => CD
        [odometer] => 89887
        [odometer_difference] => 6887
        [odometer_difference_abs] => 6887
        [price] => 15100
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you know that you can compare arrays with `==`?

```
<?php

$a = array( 'a' => 'alpha', 'b' => 'bravo' );
$b = array( 'a' => 'alpha', 'b' => 'bravo' );
$c = array( 'a' => 'alpha', 'c' => 'charlie' );
$d = array( 'c' => 'charlie', 'a' => 'alpha' );

var_dump(
    $a == $b, // true
    $a === $b, // true
    $a != $c, // true (different keys/values)
    $c == $d, // true
    $c !== $d // true (no identity! - different order of keys)
);
```

With that in mind it should be quite simple to

1. remove transaction_id, date with unset() (from the original or a shadow)
2. compare the three resulting arrays against each other
3. re-insert transaction_id, date (if you didn't shadow your original data)

You could also

1. copy array to shadow
2. remove transaction_id and date
3. sort with ksort
4. serialize() to get a string
5. sha1() to get a hash of the array
6. compare the hashes

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to write the whole solution here, since you haven't even started with any code, but here is how I would start:

I would recommend to write a compare function for simple arrays `function compare_arr(arr1, arr2, ignore_keys) { ... }`, which you can call for each sub-array in a more specific compare function for your multi-dimensional array.

Loop over the key-value pairs (foreach?) and check if the current key is in an array `ignore_keys`, then you can ignore this element, otherwise you can flag a value as duplicate.
You can abort this comparison if the values do not match.

I think the array-filter function are not helping all the way here.

Comment: I didn't start with any code because candidly I am not sure how to even start on this problem.  I am surprised this issue has not been posted previously.

Comment: @GabrielMurphy Well rodneyrehm's solution is even easier and probably more efficient, too. Try his solution.